# How to hide KDE app menubar on Unity to prevent double menubar?

Tags: unity, kde, menu-bar

How can I hide the KDE application menubar in Kdenlive? I'd like to just have on; the Unity menubar. This is Ubuntu 16.04 and Kdenlive 15.12.3.
[image]

Comment: Hello, you should add the Ubuntu version you are using.

Comment: Just disable the menubar in from app settings.

Comment: I had stability problems and updated to the latest using an AppImage. The problem doesn't occur with it and the Unity HUD integration works as well as global menu!